# How to access web page public variable from user control in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, web-user-controls

How to access the web page public variable from user control in asp .net ?

Comment: can you explain more? what you tried so for?

Comment: I want to access page vraibles from user control page. For Example usercode variable is declared in web page , mean time i want access usercode variable value from user control page..

Comment: see the answer. hope this should work. you can write server side code inside <% %> in ascx and aspx pages.

Comment: Hai atlaf , i agreed aspx page access public variable usering <% %>. But UserControl not accessed web page public variable using this method..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your page class derived from asp.net Page has this variable.

Every control has a `Page` property. If you know that this control will be placed on a particular class derived from Page, you can always cast it to the proper type. Then you have access to the public variable.

```
var propValue = ((MyControlBasePage)Page).MyProperty;
```

Ensure that the base class for the pages on which you use this control is Page derived form `MyControlBasePage`.

If you plan to use this on only one Page you could always directly use

```
var propValue = ((MyPage)Page).MyProperty;
```

But then, whats the user of a UserControl that you use on only one page.

Comment: I have create the class with name security  it inherits System.Web.UI.Page , and declared variable UserCode. My page is iherit the class security instead of System.Web.UI.Page. variable UserCode value is access in my page is fine but usercode varaible value is not accessed from usercontrol page. could you guide me..

Comment: Just type cast your `Page` property in the user control and use as shown above. Like `((security)Page).UserCode`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
<%= this.usercode %>
```